# git submodule and cmake

Tags: git, cmake

My git cmake project depends on several git submodules in which one of those submodules (libxmlmm) depends on another (libxml2). Both of those submodules are cmake-projects (I extended libxmlmm to be one). My idea is to add those project with `add_subdirectory` from my project's `CMakeLists.txt` to get one project capable of building everything.

The libxmlmm project will look for libxml2 using `find_package(libxml2)`, in which I do not want edit the libxmlmm `CMakeLists.txt`.

So what is the proper way to make the libxmlmm-project link against the libxml2 project within my project?

Comment: The only approach I can think of is to include the subdirs in an order that any subdir requiring dependencies in other submodules are added after those subdirs. To allow `find_package` to work you'd need to provide find scripts that effectively do nothing but return that the package was found. I don't like this solution and would rather replace the `find_package` code with `if(NOT TARGET libxml2) find_package(libxml2) endif()`, but that does not seem to be an option for you.